# Inequality of the determinant positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_1=\left( a_0\right)$, 
$A_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
a_0&a_1 \\
 a_1&a_0\\ 
\end{array}\right)$...
$$A_{n+1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 
a_0&a_1&\cdots&a_n \\
 a_1&a_0&\cdots&a_{n-1}\\ 
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
a_n&a_{n-1}&\cdots&a_0
\end{array}\right).$$
Suppose that $A_n$ is a positive definite matrix for each $n\geq1$.

**Q** How to show that for $n\geq2$, $$\det(A_{n+1})\leq \frac{(\det(A_n))^2}{\det(A_{n-1})}.$$

Comment: I suspect that the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) is useful here

Comment: Where did you encounter this question?  Should we expect a neat answer to exist?  Are there any tools that you suspect will apply to this problem?

Comment: Share your research.

Comment: I saw it on a Japanese version exercise. I am trying to use inductive method, but so far it does not work.

Comment: What exactly is a "Japanese version exercise"?  If this is an exercise from a textbook, then we at least know that we should be looking for a relatively simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Set $x_n=(a_n,\cdots, a_1)$. By decomposing the matrix $A_{n+1}$, we have that 
$$\frac{\det(A_{n+1})}{\det(A_n)}=a_0-x_nA^{-1}_nx^T_n.$$
It suffices to show  that $x_nA^{-1}_nx^T_n\geq x_{n-1}A^{-1}_{n-1}x^T_{n-1}$.
We regard $x_nA^{-1}_nx'^T_n$ as a quadratic function of $a'_n$ for $x'_n=(a'_n,\cdots, a'_1)$.